# SNMP Trap to defined sink

Tags: snmp, snmp-trap

I am using snmp traps and i am able to send the traps from the commandline with snmptrap. There i need to define the sink for the snmp trap but the IP address is configurable via a configuration. The configuration writes the IP address in the snmp.conf file as trap2sink. Is there a possibility to call the snmptrap command without an ip address and that the trap is then automatically send to the defined sink in the config file?!

Answer (score 1):

Try In your **snmp.conf**:

```
defTarget snmptrap domain ip:port
```

,where

- *domain* is protocol (tcp\udp\IPv6\ssh and so on)
- *ip:port* is IP and port (127.0.0.1:162)

Comment: Maybe complement this answer by adding an example of the snmptrap command line to send a trap to the new target?